# I am not able to update list pushed into array using push function and get same old values even after update list

Tags: angular

```js
     export class ApproveComponent implements OnInit {
       @Output() public next: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
       codes: any[] = [];
       selectedCode: any;
     
     this.Apiservice.komm.subscribe(data => {
     this.selectedCode = data; //this one give me right values before and efter                                 //changes in list
      console.log('selected kom ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedKom));
      for (const d of data ) {           
          this.codes.push(d.code);
           console.log('codes = ' + this.codes);
           //this.codes.push(d.code); this give me the same values before and               //efter changes
        
      }
     });
```

this code has one problem , you can see that i am getting values from service class and pushing list into  this.codes.push(d.code); as soon i populate array using push function and save it than it's ok. but i have update button in template which take me to respective list from where i get all these data list value, when i change the list with new values, i get right values in this code of segment (this.selectedCode) this show me updated values, but this code of segment(this.codes.push(d.code);
console.log('codes = ' + this.codes) ) shows me old values and doest not update the list, I hope i explained it, can some one help me with this how can i solve this issue, any kind of help be appriciated

Comment: is the length of this.codes growing when you update?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if you're saying it's duplicating the values, or the array isn't changing at all?

Comment: Try clearing up your this.codes values first, to see whether the list is really updated or not. before entering the loop, put a code there, like this: this.codes = [];, if it doesn't work, I think there is a problem elsewhere not in that code block you've shown.

Comment: this logic works for me, i place this line of code(this.codes = []) before loop and got updated list inside loop. Thanx Lot

Answer (score 0):

The this.Apiservice.komm Observable might not have data at the beginning, you can do a null check around the for loop:

```
this.Apiservice.komm.subscribe(data => {
     this.selectedCode = data; 

     if(data && data.length > 0)
          for (const d of data ) {           
              this.codes.push(d.code);
               console.log('codes = ' + this.codes);
          }
     }
});
```

If that works, I would suggest you create a private method to handle the logic.

Comment: no this logic does not working , there is no need of length check, whenever i change data in api i got correct data here this.selectedCode = data; , this is show me right update values, but inside for loop (this.codes) not update and show me the same old values i got first time. is there any alternative to push method? or how can i update this.code with new values got into this.selectedCode or data?